# dojo - added a dom node not styled correctly

Tags: dojo

I have added the following to act as a label for a dijit Select;

```
domConstruct.create('label',  
   {class:'tj-button-label', innerHTML:'Database',  
    for:'db-select'},'place-here');
```

like so

```
<ContentPane>  
   <label class='tj-button-label'>Label</label>  
   <dijit Select>...</dijit Select>  
</ContentPane>
```

with this styling

```
.tjButtonLabel{  
    width:120px;  
    background-color:#EEEFEF;  
 }
```

The node is added to a dijit ContentPane just before the Select. According to Firebug everything is placed correctly and looks fine. I can easily change the color, margins, padding and fonts, but cannot change the width.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- In your HTML you seem to have the class `tj-button-label`; in your CSS you are selecting the class `tjButtonLabel`.  Those need to match.
- You will need to set your label's `display` style to `inline-block` so that the element has a block for the width to apply to.